# Cache offset, cache index, cache tag

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-cache

So i Have physical memory/cache system with following properties:
-Physical memory is byte addressable
-Memory accesses ate to 1-byte words (not 4-byte words)
-Physical addresses are 12 bits wide
-The cache is 4-way set associative, with  a 2-byte block size and 32 total lines.
I need to find cache offset, set index, and tag fields.
So we have E=4, B=2, S=8 (32 lines/4 way set).

`C(index) = log2(S)= log2(8) = 3.
C(tag)= m - (s+b), where s = C(index) = 3.
b = log2(B) = log2(2) = 1, so C (offset) = 1.
C(tag) = 12 - (3+1) = 8.`

Hence, CO= 1, CI = 3, CT = 8. 
Is this correct? Im not sure if this is right, because not sure if C offset can be 1?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> with a 2-byte block size and 32 total lines.

Do you mean that each set has 32 lines? Then the index-bits should be 5.

If you mean that the cache has 32 lines in total, 8 per set then the index bits should be 3, just as you have stated. The offset-bits is 1.